# Evaluate $\int \frac{\mathrm dx}{1+\cos^2 x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

$$\int \frac{1}{1+\cos ^2x} \,\mathrm dx$$

I have to integrate the expression above: I tried with substitutions $\cos x=t$ and $1+(\cos x)^2=t$, but those didn't work, and I couldn't find any useful way to use bisection and duplication formulas.

Any ideas?

Comment: $cos(x)=t$ should work...

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: [To compute integrals of all rational functions of trigonometric functions.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution)

Comment: ${\sec^{2}\left(x\right) \over \tan^{2}\left(x\right) + 2}$.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{1+\cos ^2x}=\int\frac{\sec^2x\,\mathrm dx}{\sec^2x+1}=\int\frac{\sec^2x\,\mathrm dx}{2+\tan^2x}$$

And then $$\tan x=t\iff \sec^2x\,\mathrm dx=\mathrm dt$$

Comment: Thanks! That really helped!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my soliution will be helful too.$$\int \frac{dx}{1+cos^2x} = \int \frac{dx}{cos^2x(\frac{1}{cos^2x}+1)} =  [\frac{1}{cos^2x}dx=d(tgx)]= \int \frac{d(tgx)}{1+tg^2x+1} = \int \frac{d(tgx)}{tg^2x+2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}arctg(\frac{tgx}{\sqrt2})+C$$
Also we here remember trigonometry formula $\frac{1}{cos^2x}=1+tg^2x$.